# Running Focal Stats on specific values in Python?

Tags: arcpy, raster-calculator

I'm a beginning programmer.

I'm trying to recreate a raster calculator operation using python scripts but am having a hard time getting it to run properly.

I want to : check a raster for null or 0 values and use focal statistics to patch holes only on those values. In ArcGis 10.3 my raster calculation looks like this and works fine:

```
Con( IsNull(Rasterin.tif),FocalStatistics(Rasterin.tif,NbrRectangle(5,5"Cell"), "MEAN")Rasterin.tif)
```

In Python I have tried to approaches to try to recreate this.

I've tried a while statement to find these values but it does the entire raster instead of patching only the values I want ( in this case 0 so the cursors can find it in the raster table:

```
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("BadRaster.tif",['Value'])
neighborhood = NbrRectangle(5, 5, "CELL")

while True:
    try:
        for row in cursor:
            for value in row:
                    if value == 0:
                        print 'Patching......'
                        outFocalStatistics = FocalStatistics("BadRaster.tif",     neighborhood, "MINIMUM","")
                        print 'Saving stats....'
                        outFocalStatistics.save("PatchedRaster.tif")
                        print 'Checking...'
                        break
                    break
    except:
        break

print "Finished Patching"

del cursor
```

And I've tried using it with map algebra :

```
neighborhood = NbrRectangle(5, 5, "CELL")
con = Con(("BadRaster.tif" < 1,0,0),FocalStatistics("BadRaster.tif", neighborhood, "MEAN",""))

arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa(con,"PatchedRaster.tif")
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, can you try to make the selection manually within the table in ArcMap and run the tool?  If that works, you will have to include select by attribute logic if value == 0:.  In addition, you do not need the for value in row: statment and the if value == 0: should be if row[0] == 0:.

Answer (score 1):

Your last attempt with map algebra is almost there. Try:

```
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('spatial') #not required if run from within ArcMap with Spatial Analyst already enabled
neighborhood = NbrRectangle(5, 5, "CELL")
in_raster = Raster("BadRaster.tif")
out_raster = Con(IsNull(in_raster), FocalStatistics(in_raster, neighborhood, "MEAN",""), in_raster)
out_raster.save("PatchedRaster.tif")
```